# Reading feather file from a url in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, feather

I am using api gateway proxy for s3 to read feather files. Below is the simplest form of the code I am using.

```
import pandas as pd

s3_data=pd.read_feather('https://<api_gateway>/<bucket_name/data.feather>')
```

This gives an error -

```
   reader = _feather.FeatherReader(source, use_memory_map=memory_map)
  File "pyarrow\_feather.pyx", line 75, in pyarrow._feather.FeatherReader.__cinit__
  File "pyarrow\error.pxi", line 143, in pyarrow.lib.pyarrow_internal_check_status
  File "pyarrow\error.pxi", line 114, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
OSError: Verification of flatbuffer-encoded Footer failed.
```

If I keep the feather file on my local and read it like below, all works fine.

```
s3_data=pd.read_feather("file://localhost//C://Users//<Username>//Desktop//data.feather")
```

How do I make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the gateway proxy needs to do some redirection, that makes it fail.  I would have done something like this:

```
from s3fs import S3FileSystem

fs = S3FileSystem(anon=True)
with fs.open("<bucket>/data.feather") as f:
    df = pd.read_feather(f)
```

[s3fs](https://github.com/dask/s3fs/) is part of Dask.  There are also other similar layers that you can use.

**PS:** if you are using feather for long term data storage, the Apache Arrow project advises against it (maintainer of feather).  You should probably use parquet.